# Криптография и криптоаналитика

Tags: книги, криптография, криптоаналитика

Прошу сообщить какие-нибудь хорошие книги по криптографии и криптоаналитике.

Что именно интересует?

История, теория, практика, математическое объяснение, программная реализация и тд и тп. В общем материалы, которые помогут разобраться в этом. И не обязательно IT'шные книги.

Comment: Правильно это называется Криптография и Криптоаналитика. Первое по шифрованию, второе по дешифровке соответственно.

Comment: @BlackOverlord, учту

Comment: Что-то я загорелся после прочтения "Цифровой крепости"

Comment: Я, правда, не шибко в курсе, но не «криптоанализ» ли правильное слово, вместо какой-то странной «криптоаналитики»?

Как название профессии оно — да, правильно, но не как название дисциплины.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Начните с классики - "Прикладная криптография" Брюса Шнайера.

Comment: @Nofate, Брюса Шнайера «Прикладная криптография. Протоколы, алгоритмы, исходные тексты на языке Си»  

Без знания языка С стоит начинать читать эту книгу? Просто, если в основе книги не ЯП, а именно криптография, то без разницы, какой язык я знаю...

Comment: Стоит. В основе - математика.

Еще для вдохновения можно почитать "Криптономикон" Нила Стивенсона. )

Comment: ок. спасибо  
PS. почитал описание Криптономикона. После вышеупомянутой цифровой крепости, с удовольствием почитаю) Может даже первым делом)

Comment: таки купил Криптономикон) Купленная книга, как назло, оказалось чуть ли не единственной в городе, так что пришлось побегать

Comment: @teanЫЧ читал Цифровую крепость и долго смеялся - бредятина полная...

Comment: @Barmaley, нуу.. а что вы хотели? Автор поставил перед собой задачу - написать интересный, лехко читаемый роман. Задачу он выполнил. То, что он ничего не понимает ни в математике, ни в программировании, ни в криптографии - это, конечно, его минус. Но сюжет интересный, оригинальный, атмосфера есть, поэтому я не старался обращать внимании на некоторые неточности и откровенные технические глупости. Просто расслабился и постарался получить удовольствие.
Ну вы тоже молодец, хотите почитать попсу, чтобы получить какие-то полезные знания?

Answer (score 5):

Брюс Шнайер - Прикладная криптография.

[Курс на Udacity](http://www.udacity.com/view#Course/cs387/CourseRev/apr2012/Unit/4001/Nugget/6001)

[Курс на Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto)

Answer (score 3):

С начала ноября открыт [онлайн-курс по криптографии](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto). Рассказывает профессор из Стэнфорда. Правда, уже прошла половина первой части курса, но будет и [вторая часть](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto2), которая начнётся в январе.

Все лекции, естественно на английском, но это не должно пугать.

Answer (score 2):

[Практическая криптография +CD - Масленников М.Е.](http://www.bookzone.com.ua/Netshop/catalogue/catalogue_6915.html)

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток. К выше сказанному, если тема еще актуальна. 
Вильям Столлингс "Криптография и защита сетей. Принципы и практика" довольно доступно расписано.